# Sorting Values in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a newbie to Python and not fully sure how to work with dictionaries. I want to sort one of the dictionaries with another one. So I have something like given below. Each of the vertex features is a list.

```
vertex_features = ['Charge', 'Time', 'TimeDelta', 'TimeSinceLastPulse']
..........
..........
a = {feature : [] for feature in vertex_features }
```

I want to sort the Time feature (and get the corresponding Charge, Time Delta etc.), which I did by

```
hit_order = np.argsort(features['Time'])
```

However when I try

```
for feature in features:
    features[feature] = features[feature][hit_order]
```

It gives the error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I have also tried

```
for feature in features:
    features[feature] = features[feature][for i in hit_order]
```

But unable to get the sorted lists.
I am not fully sure if I understand what I am doing wrong with the sorting here. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to convert your list to a np.array first and then back to a list if you want it to be a list. Otherwise I'd just start out with np.array instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've come across is Python Lists don't support reording via the square bracket syntax. This is a feature of Numpy Arrays.

When you use square brackets on a Python List, the interpreter is either expecting a scalar index or some kind of slice.

Instead of using a List, you can wrap the feature list returned from the dict in np.array as below:

```
import numpy as np

vertex_features = ['Charge', 'Time', 'TimeDelta', 'TimeSinceLastPulse']
features = {feature: [] for feature in vertex_features}

hit_order = np.argsort(features['Time'])

for feature in features:
    features[feature] = np.array(features[feature])[hit_order]
```

Or when you declare your dict comprehension, wrap the list:

```
import numpy as np

vertex_features = ['Charge', 'Time', 'TimeDelta', 'TimeSinceLastPulse']
features = {feature: np.array([]) for feature in vertex_features}

hit_order = np.argsort(features['Time'])

for feature in features:
    features[feature] = features[feature][hit_order]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It works. However I have a question (might be stupid). In the first answer  for feature in features:
    features[feature] = np.array(features[feature])[hit_order] ; It doesn't work when I close the round brackets. Why is it so?

Comment: @ParasKoundal I'm not sure to be honest, you might just want to double check your code. It seems to run okay in my interpreter on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

A numpy `ndarray` and a Python `list` are different animals. They can be trivially converted back and forth, but only a `ndarray` can accept another `ndarray` as index. For Python lists, the idiomatic way is to use a comprehension.

As `features` contains plain lists you must choose one way:

1. convert to numpy array:

   ```
   for feature in features:
       features[feature] = np.array(features[feature])[hit_order]
   ```
2. build a list with a comprehension:

   ```
   for feature in features:
       features[feature] = [features[feature][i] for i in hit_order]
   ```